# Resetting counters with states

Tags: flutter

I'm just learning Flutter and I seem to be stuck on what is probably a very simple task, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. All I want to do is reset all the counters back to 0. Perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way which is why I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight, DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/thumbsup.png'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    //reset all counters
                  }),
              expandedHeight: 150.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('Welcome to Logie & Lana\'s Drive Thru', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),),
                centerTitle: false,
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
              ),
            ),
            SliverGrid.count(
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              childAspectRatio: 1.2,
              children: <Widget>[
                MyCounter('bigmac-small.png'),
                MyCounter('mcdonalds-fries.png'),
                MyCounter('mcnuggets.png'),
                MyCounter('coke.png'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  final String image;

  MyCounter(this.image);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyCounter(image);
  }
}


class _MyCounter extends State<MyCounter> {
  int counter;
  String image;

  _MyCounter(this.image);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return RaisedButton(
      highlightColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
      splashColor: Colors.red,
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          counter++;
        });
      },
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            'assets/$image',
            height: 150.0,
          ),
          Text(
            '$counter',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Like I said, it should be pretty simple, it's nothing more than a few buttons with a counter but it's driving me crazy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is you are trying to change the state of the child widget from the parent widget which can be done through streams if you want but if you are just starting keep all of your information which needs changed in the parent widget and call the setState from the parent widget when it needs changed.

To do this you can change the MyCounter widget to a stateless widget and pass it a closure on initialization which calls the setState method and updates the corresponding count variable using the setState method from your _MyAppState widget. Feel free to comment with any questions if something is confusing you and I will try to explain.

Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight, DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var images = Map<String,int>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    images['bigmac-small.png'] = 0;
    images['mcdonalds-fries.png'] = 0;
    images['mcnuggets.png'] = 0;
    images['coke.png'] = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/thumbsup.png'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState((){
                      images['bigmac-small.png'] = 0;
                      images['mcdonalds-fries.png'] = 0;
                      images['mcnuggets.png'] = 0;
                      images['coke.png'] = 0;
                    });
                  }),
              expandedHeight: 150.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('Welcome to Logie & Lana\'s Drive Thru', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),),
                centerTitle: false,
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
              ),
            ),
            SliverGrid.count(
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              childAspectRatio: 1.2,
              children: <Widget>[
                MyCounter('bigmac-small.png',images['bigmac-small.png'],() => setState((){images['bigmac-small.png']++;})),
                MyCounter('mcdonalds-fries.png',images['mcdonalds-fries.png'],() => setState((){images['mcdonalds-fries.png']++;})),
                MyCounter('mcnuggets.png',images['mcnuggets.png'],() => setState((){images['mcnuggets.png']++;})),
                MyCounter('coke.png',images['coke.png'],() => setState((){images['coke.png']++;})),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}

class MyCounter extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final int count;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  MyCounter(this.image, this.count, this.onPressed);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return RaisedButton(
      highlightColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
      splashColor: Colors.red,
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () => onPressed(),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            'assets/$image',
            height: 150.0,
          ),
          Text(
            '$count',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! The map is to keep track of which image it's associated with? Your way has given me a lot of great information, thanks again Bryan.

Comment: Not a problem!  If you're going to get into more complex apps I would suggest looking into the BLoC pattern which will solve a lot of these issues for you and give you a solid architecture to work from.